# Encrypt directory with GnuPG?

Tags: directory, encryption, gpg

Is there any way to encrypt a directory using `gpg`? It seems to only accept files as arguments.

Comment: There are also ways to encrypt a whole directory or drive, but they are different in scope: they offer transparent encryption (you just type a password to mount the drive), but the result can't be read by GPG or PGP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not `tar` the files to be encrypted and then encrypt the tarball?

Comment: I found this to be the solution. It is not flexible and requires a lot of resources to tar and gpg date. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @gladimdim: thanks for accepting, but what do you mean by "not flexible" and "lot of resources"?  Or was there a typo?

Comment: by "not flexible" I meant that I needed manually tar directory then gpg it. I have about 60Gb of pics which are now tarballed and gpged. It took about 2 hours and 4 concurrent terminal windows to speed up this process. Now I just tarball and gpg every new directory with pics which I create.

Comment: Hm, that seems pretty reasonable time for that size of data.  Did you expect to run it a lot faster?  What's you plan when you need one those pics--decrypt/untar all the 60Gigs?

Answer (score 2):

I just saw the option `--multifile` on the manpage:

> This  modifies  certain other commands to accept multiple files for processing on the command line or read from STDIN with each filename on a separate line. This allows for many files to be processed at once. --multi‐
>                 file may currently be used along with --verify, --encrypt, and --decrypt. Note that --multifile --verify may not be used with detached signatures.

What you are specifically looking for is `--encrypt-files` and, again the manpage:

> Identical to --multifile --encrypt.

Comment: Thanks, this works good except that gpg does not support --multiple key with --symmetric option (I want to encrypt only using passphrase).

Answer (score 2):

I've read the comments on the answer that has been marked as accepted.

Looks like you should be made aware of the magic of `|` (anonymous pipes), check [the answer I just posted on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1148339/666508) and you'll find that `tar` & `gpg` can be "joined" together so that your output is compressed and encrypted.

Note that it'll still use significant system resources so consideri using `nice`.

Also, while I'm in the mood to suggest topics that may make your life easier on the command line in general; look into file descriptors and named pipes for passing data around.

If you wish to see what kind of magic can be performed when the above subjects are understood, check [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/S0AndS0/Perinoid_Pipes) build logs and related scripts for solutions related to automating GnuPG on the command line.

---- Updates

As requested, an example for dealing with directories can be found within the previously mentioned script at line [680](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Perinoid_Pipes/blob/376e26395099ecf31dee2920b4987aceee40761c/Paranoid_Pipes.sh#L680) and a more generalized example would be...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dir_path="${1:?${0##*/} needs a directory path as the first argument}"
default_gpg_email="your-email@host.domain"
gpg_email="${2:-$default_gpg_email}"
_dir_name="${dir_path##*/}"
_dir_name="${_dir_name%/*}"
Var_star_date="$(date -u +%s)"

if [ -d "${dir_path}" ]; then
    tar -cz - "${dir_path}" | gpg --always-trust --armor --batch --no-tty --encrypt --recipient ${gpg_email} > /tmp/${Var_star_date}_${_dir_name}.tgz.gpg"
else
    echo "${0##*/} operates on directories"
    exit 1
fi
```

... which maybe run with `script-name.sh /path/to/dir` or `script-name.sh /path/to/dir new-email@host.domain` and *should* output to the `/tmp` directory a file `<current-date>_<top-dir-name>.tgz.gpg`

Comment: Can you write an example ?

Comment: Yep, though it may take me a bit :-D

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know of a way to encrypt a whole directory but here is a command that will encrypt all of the files within a directory ending with .csv.

find . -name "*.csv" -exec gpg --cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric --passphrase-file .passphrase  --batch --yes {} ;